# C++ public enum in namespace of class

Tags: c++, class, oop, enums, gpio

I am making a class and I want to create an enum inside that class so that it can only be accessed through the namespace of that class. I would want users to be able to access the enum outside of the class like so:

```
GpioPin pin(23, GpioPin::OUTPUT);
```

where GpioPin is the class and OUTPUT is one of the enum values.

I tried putting the enum at the top of the class and I tried putting it under the public label like (constructor included for help debugging):

```
public:
    enum pin_dir {
        INPUT,
        OUTPUT,
    };

    GpioPin(int pin_num, pin_dir dir): pin_num(pin_num), dir(dir) {
        std::string dir_str; 
        if(dir == INPUT){
            dir_str = "in";
        } else if (dir == OUTPUT){
            dir_str = "out";
        } else {
            std::cout << "invalid direction in constructor for pin " << pin_num << std::endl;
            return;
        }

        init_gpio_pin(pin_num, dir_str.c_str());
    }
```

but when under the public tag the constructor acts like the enum doesn't exist and throws a compiler error.

Does anyone know the proper way to do this?

Thanks

Edit: the problem has been solved. The code that is depicted here is correct and works as intended. The accepted answer gives some good information about enum class in C++

Comment: Can we get a [mre] of the code that does not work?  Also, please include the full error text.  Paraphrasing often loses valuable information.

Comment: sure I'll edit it in a sec. the error text is very long and involves a lot of different errors that all stem from the main issue that the compiler thinks that the enum type doesn't exist

Comment: [Cannot Reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5e246f3fac82ecdc)

Comment: It the OS is Linux, I would recommend to use `libgpiod`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at enum class (google for c++ enum class).

```
Class Foo {
public:
    enum class Color{ Red, Green, Blue};
};
```

Then, you reference things as:

```
Foo::Color::Red
```

Works great.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. OP is having trouble getting a regular enum inside a class to work.

Comment: @Kevin I think it does answer his question. It's not that he's having trouble getting an enum inside his class to work -- it's a naming convention thing he's dealing with.

Comment: But OP wants users to be able to do: `GpioPin pin(23, GpioPin::OUTPUT);`. Using an enum class they would have to do: `GpioPin pin(23, GpioPin::pin_dir::OUTPUT);`

Comment: @Kevin True. Feel free to provide an answer that lets him do it exactly the way he wants. I think his goal is problematic and am suggesting he modify it ever-so-slightly. Maybe what he's trying to do is possible, but no one has actually provided a working answer. (Not yet, as I type this.)

Comment: What the OP wrote should work (if written into full code). There isn't enough information to answer why it didn't work or what needs to be fixed, which is why a [mcve] was requested.

Comment: This worked great for me and was exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: So the code that I put should work as expected? @Kevin

Comment: @Dyskord What you have shown us should work, yes. You need to provide us with a [mcve] so we can help you understand the problem.

Comment: if that's the case it probably was a grammatical error and not a big problem. The knowledge that in the future I can set up an enum this way would be more important to me and probably to others who see this post. Thank you!

Comment: @Kevin I included the constructor for my class. Is this the proper way to use said enum? the constructor plus the enum declaration plus the constructor should give you enough to determine a problem if there was one. Note that I did fix up grammar so the error may not be there anymore (I think the enum declaration might have been missing a semicolon) , just want to make sure this works.

Comment: @Dyskord [Yes, that works](https://godbolt.org/z/3cr1jn)